# oracle comments on column of object type table

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

i have an object type

```
create or replace type header_o as object(
col1 number, 
col2 number, 
col3 number);
```

then i create table

```
create table tab1(
id number, 
header header_o);
```

so I want to make comment on `header.col1`

when i try

```
comment on column tab1.header.col1 is 'comment goes here';
```

oracle raises missing keyword.

 How can i make this work?

Answer (score 2):

> oracle comments on column of object type table

No, you cannot. Oracle doesn't support this feature.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm), you could add comments to:

- table, view, or materialized view
- indextype
- operator

While, you are trying to add comment to an **object type**. You could add comments to the table **column**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE type header_o
  2  AS
  3    object
  4    (
  5      col1 NUMBER,
  6      col2 NUMBER,
  7      col3 NUMBER)
  8  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE tab1
  2    ( ID NUMBER, header header_o
  3    )
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN tab1.HEADER IS 'comment goes here'
  2  /

Comment created.
```

Comment: it is really raising `missing keyword` , and the thing is that i don't want to make comment on `header`,  i want it on header.col1. because when i query the table i want to see the comment of `col1` not entire header. i guess it is not possible?

Comment: @arminrock As I said, you could add comments to a table column and not on the object type.

Answer (score 2):

The COMMENT syntax dates from way back in the mists of time, from before object types.  So it only supports TABLE.COLUMN

I imagine that it could be possible to extend it to support TABLE.COLUMN.ATTRIBUTE.  The complexity is that types can be constructed out of types, which can be constructed out of types, and so on.  This means the implementation of the syntax would be much more complex.  That's probably one reason why Oracle didn't embark on it.

The other reason might be that so few people bother to put comments on columns or tables, it probably didn't seem worth the effort.

Either way, I'm afraid it's a change request.